# forward from heroku app hosted on cedar-14 stack?

Tags: heroku

Is there a way to forward traffic from an old heroku app hosted on their (no longer supported) cedar-14 stack to the new version of the app (on heroku-18)? I can no longer build to the cedar-14 site. Both apps are using Heroku's default domains, [app name].herokuapp.com.

Comment: Why not just upgrade the stack on your existing domain / app?

Comment: Or delete the old app on Heroku and then immediately create the new one under that name.

Comment: I hear you.  I want to keep the old code around for a month to make sure that the new code works ok.

Comment: I think the solution is to do what @jonrsharpe suggests without deleting the old site.  The steps are:  1)  Change name of old site to [old_site_name_backup] hosted at [old_site_name_backup].herokuapp.com.  2)  Change the new site's name to [old_site_name] hosted at [old_site_name].herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to keep the old code in case it is needed while directing people visiting the old domain access to the newly written site.  This can be accomplished with carefully sequenced site name changes.  [Heroku describes how to change site names here.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps#updating-git-remotes)  You will also have to update git remotes and such on your local machine but the Heroku instructions tell you how to do that, too.

The now somewhat obvious sequence is:

1. change name of [old site] to something like [old_site]-backup
2. change name of [new site] to [old site]